# How do I add it so when the button is clicked it plays the audio file in html

Tags: html, audio

Here is the lines I'm using for the audio on click, but what am I doing wrong?

```
<script>
var snd = new Audio('click.mp3');
</script>
<a href='index.html'><snd.play(); snd.currentTime=0; button class="button button1">Home</button><a>
```

Comment: **General tip:** The syntax highlighting should give you a clue the code won't work. I try to always use code editors with syntax highlighting for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

I extended the code from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio with a click-handler. This should work.

```html
<script>
var snd = new Audio('click.mp3');
snd.addEventListener("canplaythrough", event => {
  /* the audio is now playable; play it if permissions allow */
  document.querySelector('.button').addEventListener("click", e => {
    snd.play();
  });
});
</script>
<a href='index.html'></a><button class="button button1">Home</button>
```

**Edit:** To play a sound on click will only works if the user stay on your site. When you open a link (the `<a>`) this will not work reasonable.

Comment: Ok so i just tested this and it work great, although its as if the sound has a refresh time, how can the code be modified in such a way that it plays litterly on click, so it plays even when being spammed, if you understand

Comment: It also only is working for home button and not the rest, i only started learning html today btw

`var snd = new Audio('click.mp3');
snd.addEventListener("canplaythrough", event => {
document.querySelector('.button').addEventListener("click", e => {
snd.play();
});
});
</script>
<a href='index.html'></a><button class="button button1">Home</button>
<a href='social.html'></a><button class="button button1">Socials</button>
<a href='game.html'></a><button class="button button1">Game</button>
<a href='python.html'></a><button class="button button1">Python</button>`

Comment: You have to add an event-listener for each button: `document.querySelectorAll('.button').forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener("click", e => {snd.play();}));`

Comment: Ok so im struggling,

` var snd = new Audio('click.mp3');

  snd.addEventListener("canplaythrough", event => {

    document.querySelectorAll('.button').forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener("click", e => {

      snd.play();

    }));

  });`


What is wrong here, https://replit.com/join/zyqghiku-16cookj, join that link to view my code and edit because this stuff is all new to me!!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to play some audio, just use the HTML 5 Audio Tag:

```
<audio src="click.mp3" controls></audio>
```

Also see [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp)

When recording is the thing you want to do, see [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Using_the_MediaStream_Recording_API)

Comment: Yes, that works but only singularly not on click, i have been using W3Schools and it has been so useful

Comment: With the `controls` attribute set you, as a user, have the control if the audio file starts playing or not. Is [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_audio.asp) example not working for you?